# Height of Status Bar with Call notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I would like to get the height of the status bar. this I use normally

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

but when I press Cmd + Y in the simulator, the call status bar appears and my View Controller will move down.

Is there any function like at the top to get the height of this call status bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple Documentation:

> **UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification**
>
> Posted when the app
>   is about to change the frame of the status bar. The `userInfo`
>   dictionary contains an `NSValue` object that encapsulates a `CGRect`
>   structure expressing the location and size of the new status bar
>   frame. Use `UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey` to access this
>   value.

After you access to CGRect of the new frame of status bar, you can figure out the height of "call status bar" which is equal to `{frame of status bar}.origin.y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ObjC
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame
{
    NSLog(@"Status bar height %f", CGRectGetHeight(newStatusBarFrame));
}

// Swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
      print(newStatusBarFrame)
}
```